# Django: Saving oauth provider data

Tags: django, oauth, django-allauth, django-fixtures

I set up a simple django site using django-allauth.

I created some oauth providers in the database.

Everything is fine and working on my laptop now.

I would like to store the created database tables somehow.

Use case: I want to set up a new development environments on a different PC painlessly.

How to store the initial data of django_allauth, so that after checking out the app from git the command `manage.py migrate` is all I need to have the relevant database tables filled?

Answer (score 0):

Django_allauth already save those data to the database, you will find them in a table `*_SocialApp`, [here is](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/socialaccount/models.py#L35) the model code from django_auth source

Comment: OK, the data gets stored in the database table. My question is: how to set up a new development version of my app and let this data automatically get entered into the database?